# IllegalStateException Running Grails Services Unit Tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, grails-3.3

I have a simple grails service:

```
@Transactional
class SearchService {
    def doSomething() {
        10
    }
}
```

with a simple unit test:

```
class SearchServiceSpec extends Specification implements ServiceUnitTest<SearchService>{

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
        expect:
        service.doSomething() == 10
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following exception:

[image]

Anyone know what this means?

Strange thing is it works if I change `doSomething` to `getSomething` and then do `service.something`.

I have following versions:
| Grails Version: 3.3.0
| Groovy Version: 2.4.11
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_60

Comment: Using a 'get' method is exactly what they have in the documentation : https://testing.grails.org/latest/guide/index.html#unitTestingServices

Add a @Mock() annotation to your class and it should wire GORM and work. (Grails prior to 3.3). I don't know how they changed it in 3.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the getter method is not having transactional behavior applied to it. To test a transactional method, you need to have a GORM implementation setup. The easiest way to do that for your test is to implement `grails.testing.gorm.DataTest`.

Comment: It would be nice to have this documented in the official documentation in the 'unit testing services' section. Since Services are generated with transactional behavior by default, it's an important fact to have in the documentation.

Comment: Then I would encourage you to submit a PR to the documentation.

Comment: That fixed it. I agree with @bassmartin I couldn't have figured this out without a SO post.